# Change sprite plist file in the init - cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a game in cocos2d and I have a knight character that I want to change the sprite for. So in my knight.m, I did this:

```
- (id)initWithKnightPicture {

        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL3.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL3.plist"];

        self = [super initWithFile:l1];


    if (self) {

                [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:l1_plist];

        // ************* RUNNING ANIMATION ********************
        animationFramesRun = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
            [animationFramesRun addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level1-Run-hd-%d.png", i]]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if ([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] game].fatness < 20) {
        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL1.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL1.plist"];
    } else if ([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] game].fatness < 40) {
        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL2.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL2.plist"];
    } else if ([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] game].fatness < 60) {
        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL3.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL3.plist"];
    } else if ([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] game].fatness < 80) {
        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL4.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL4.plist"];
    } else if ([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] game].fatness < 100) {
        l1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL5.png"];
        l1_plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"knightL5.plist"];
    }
}
```

So basically, I want the knight's sprite to change from `knightL1.plist` to `knightL2.plist` based on the fatness of the knight... So what I am doing in my code is, I am assigning the knight to be the string `l1` and assigning `l1` and `l1_plist` to be `knightL3` in the `init`. Then in my update method, I am changing `l1` and `l1_plist` to be a different string. The problem is, that if the fatness does exceed `80`, and I change the `l1` and `l1_plist` strings to be a different string, the sprite does not change from being `knightL4.plist` to `knightL5.plist`. So how can I make it so the knight changes based on the fatness as the game progresses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for being vague... I updated my question

Comment: what's the content of your update method ? that's where you should handle your animations and the whatnots, init methods have one purpose which is for initialising objects. can you clarify a bit more what's the issue ?

Comment: I updated my question with some more edits and new code

Comment: hmmm, do you mean it works for fatness between 20 and 60 and when it's 80 or above it stops working ?

Comment: yeah that's cause i can see in your update method you're just setting `l1` and `l1_plist` to strings and not doing anything with them, perhaps you should do something after the last line ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49365/discussion-between-mostafa-torbjorn-berg-and-shalin-shah)

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted should work. Try stepping through it in the debugger with fatness > 80 and see what lines are executed.